# Where to download fonts to fix particular Korean letters being displayed as boxes on PyCharm?

Tags: fonts, language, pycharm

I am using PyCharm (with Python 3.6.1) on two PC's. The file encoding (UTF-8) and font (Segoe UI) settings are identical. On one PC, I have no problems. But on the other, certain Korean letters are displayed as boxes.

For example, when I type 강아지 in the script, ☐아지 shows up. From reading [Specific characters displaying as boxes in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/647418/specific-characters-displaying-as-boxes-in-windows-7), I am guessing that this is because the font for 강 doesn't exist in the second PC -- despite sharing the same font with the first.

Can I download some font and load it onto PyCharm of the second PC to fix this problem? If so, where can I download it?

Note that 강아지 is displayed properly elsewhere on the second PC, e.g. notepad, MS Word.